# WOT Continuous operators

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $E$ be a Banach space, I'm trying to figure out the trick to prove that all the WOT-continuous operators $\phi:B(E)\to\mathbb{C}$ are of the form

$$\phi(T) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\varphi_{i}(Tx_{i})$$

for some $\varphi_{i}\in E^{*}$, $x_{i}\in E$.

---

That is, the following are equivalent:

(1) If $\varphi(T_{n}x)\to 0$ for all $\varphi\in E^{*},x\in E$, then $\phi(T)\to 0$.

(2) There exist $x_{1},...,x_{n}\in E, \varphi_{1},...,\varphi_{n}\in E^{*}$ such that $\phi(T) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\varphi_{i}(Tx_{i})$ for all $T\in B(E)$.

---

$\bf{\text{Context}}$:  This appears as an exercise which is referred to in a proof.  I think solving this exercise is a pre-requisite to following the proof.

---

(2) implies (1) is a one line check, but I can't seem to figure out how to come up with the $x_{i},\varphi_{i}$'s for the other direction.  Anyone know the trick off hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition of continuity, there exists a WOT neighborhood of $0$ in $B(E)$ in which $|\phi|<1$. Restate this more explicitly, using the structure of WOT neighborhoods: there exist $x_1,\dots,x_n\in E$ and $\varphi_1,\dots,\varphi_n\in E^*$ such that 
$$\max_i|\varphi_i(Tx_i)|< 1\implies |\phi(T)|<1 \tag{1}$$
By homogeneity, (1) automatically amplifies to 
$$|\phi(T)| \le \max_i|\varphi_i(Tx_i)| \qquad \forall T\in B(E) \tag{2}$$
Let's restate this in terms of the  map $\psi:B(E)\to \mathbb C^n$ defined by $\psi(T)=(\varphi_i(Tx_i))_{i=1}^n$. Since $\phi$ vanishes on the kernel of $\psi$, we can write $\phi=\chi\circ \psi$ for some linear map $\chi:\mathbb C^n\to \mathbb C$. Which is what was to be proved, since the application of $\chi$ will only shuffle and combine the vectors and linear functionals $x_i,\varphi_i$.

Comment: The fact that you used:  If $\phi$ vanishes on the kernel of $\psi$, then $\phi = \chi\circ\psi$ for some linear $\chi:\mathbb{C}^{n}\to\mathbb{C}$.  Does that still apply if $\psi$ is a map to some space $E^{n}$ for a Banach space $E$?

Comment: OK.  I think the answer is yes, using a basis for $E$ and applying the former result to each coordinate.